# Rails: Form helper for enum attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set `category`'s `viewable` attribute as an `enum`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum viewable: [:only_self, :friends, :anyone]
end
```

How should I make them accesible in `_form` when users edit this attribute? Something like?

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:viewable) %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE------

```
  <%= f.select(:viewable, options_for_select([["description1", "only_self"], ["description2", "friends"], ["description3", "anyone"]])) %>
```

1. The description for each is quite repetative, because I need to put them whenever I need to display, not just in the forms. Where should I put them?
2. In `form_for`, the `f.select` does not display the current value of the this field. It always is the first `description1`.

Comment: explain the 2nd point in your update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the plural form, rails provides the full key/value array, so you can call `Category.viewables` for the array, and with the help of `options_for_select` you'll get a nice functioning dropdown list

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:viewable, options_for_select(Category.viewables)) %>
<% end %>
```

**Updated answers**

> The description for each is quite repetative, because I need to put
>   them whenever I need to display, not just in the forms. Where should I
>   put them?

You can use the `I18n` library, assuming your locale is chinese (zh i think) then you could create `/config/locales/zh.yml` and add something like this

```
categories:
  viewable:
    only_self: 'some chinese text'
    friend: 'more chinese text'
    anyone: 'well you know'
```

Then better create some helper that returns the localized options

```
def options_for_viewables
  { 
    t('categories.viewable.only_self') => 0,
    t('categories.viewable.friends') => 1,
    t('categories.viewable.anyone') => 2
  }
end
```

The view will become like this

```
<%= f.select(:viewable, options_for_viewables) %>
```

Comment: I've update my question. Could you help me with this? As for the `description` of enum, I'm using chinese, so the english value is quite unfriendly to my users.

Comment: Yeah, it works, Thankyou. But `def options_for_viewables` should just be a block, not `[]` needed.

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady When I did that in your way, I've got an error:
    
     '1' is not a valid period_units

So, I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24195129/3134155) is the right way doing this.

Comment: I can't tell what is the problem with your case, but i know this should work cause I already used this in many cases, if you have a question on SO you can give me the link and I'll take a look